# Call functions in Python Nested List

Tags: python, recursion, nested-loops, nested-lists

I need to iterate over nested lists in python, where the list items are function calls (first item in list is the function, any remaining items are the arguments to that function).
These arguments can also themselves be functions with arguments, hence the nesting. A list can also contain a single function with no arguments.
Like so:
`['foo','arg1','arg2']`
Or:
`[['foo','arg1','arg2'],['bar'],['baz','arg1']]`
Or:
`['foo','arg1',['baz','arg1']]`
Etc.

Here's an example using fictitious sum and product functions... Sum adds, Product multiplies; If we evaluated the functions we'd get 10.

['sum',['product',2,3],4]

I can just pass the function and arguments to another function that does the actual 'calling' of my safe functions, but I'm having trouble actually iterating over the list recursively.
Here's a sad attempt:

```
def process_list(l):
        if isinstance(l,list):
            results = []
            for item in l:
                if isinstance(item,list):
                    func = item[0]
                    args = item[1:]
                    for idx, arg in enumerate(args):
                        if isinstance(arg,list):
                            args[idx] = process_list(arg)
                    results.append(function_caller_result(func,args)) #what if that's a list?
                else:
                    results.append(item)
            return results
        return l
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to build kind of a recursive function, but manually. That won't work if the nesting is greater than what you coded.

Write a recursive function instead:

```
my_list = ['sum',['product',2,3],4]

def process(l):
    l = l.copy()
    for item in l:
        if isinstance(item,list):
            l.replace(item, process(item))
    return function_caller_result(*l) 
    # suppose l = [1, [2], '3']
    # func(*l) => func(1, [2], '3')

result = process(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with unpacking:

```
eval_d = {'sum':lambda x, y:x+y, 'product':lambda x, y:x*y} #dict to store function names with an associated callable
data = [['sum',['product',2,3],4]]
def eval_f(d):
   r = [eval_d[a](*[i if not isinstance(i, list) else eval_f([i]) for i in b]) 
        for a, *b in d]
   #r now stores the result from the function calls
   return sum(r) #for this example to work, a cumulate sum is returned, but you can also just return the list

print(eval_f(data))
```

Output:

```
10
```

The goal of this solution is to work in scenarios where `eval_f` is passed a list of lists with function signatures i.e `[['foo','arg1','arg2'],['bar'],['baz','arg1']]`. As such, single function calls must be wrapped in a list to ensure that the pattern holds: `['foo','arg1','arg2']` would be passed to `eval_f` and `[['foo','arg1','arg2']]`.

Comment: @python_user I only included the final summation `return sum(r)` so that the function `eval_f` would produce a sensible result. Based on the OP's code, `r` itself should probably be returned in practice, but since we don't have the implementations of `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, it makes more sense to provide a solution that does basic expression evaluation, in the style of the OP's overall input.